# Azure functions host.json somehow being ignored

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a V2 Azure function. I have configured this function to run only one function in parallel. This is my host.json file:

`{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
  }
}`

When I start the function on my local development machine it shows the following output:

> [27-5-2019 12:43:06] Starting Rpc Initialization Service.
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:06] Initializing RpcServer
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:06] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration 
>   suppressed: False
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07] Initializing Host.
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
>
> ...
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07] QueuesOptions
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07] {
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07]   **"BatchSize": 16,**
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07]   **"NewBatchThreshold": 8,**
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07]   "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07]   "MaxDequeueCount": 5,**
>
> [27-5-2019 12:43:07]   "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"

Following this output it seems to not have registered these settings. The behaviour also shows this as the function runs in parallel instead of one at a time. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Reference to MS host.json [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)

Comment: Are you using Azure App Service Plan or Consumption Plan?

Comment: Cosumption plan, but this example is from running it in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an open issue reported [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4480), Functions Startup ignored host.json

If you have `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` in your code, removing that should recognized `host.json` correctly.

Comment: So this means we have either no DI or no host.json, not the best situation. I'll mark this as the answer for now, as there is no valid alternative

Comment: @nldev Have you tried the answer from Nick Cameron? Its working for me and many others. If you can still try and update once here will be great.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the exact same issue as Dave Parker and his analysis of a new configuration registration overwriting the host.json configuration was spot on.

As jsgoupil commented on Dave's post the `ImplementationInstance` is null though. Here's some slight updates to Dave's code to handle that.

```cs
public IConfigurationRoot AddSettings(IServiceCollection services, string basePath, string name, bool optional, bool reloadOnChange)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(basePath);

    // check if an IConfiguration has already been registered
    var existingConfig = builder.Services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType.Name == nameof(IConfiguration));
    if(existingConfig != null)
    {
        // get an instance of it and include it in the new config builder
        var sp = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var existingInstance = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        builder.AddConfiguration(existingInstance);
    }

    // Register/load the requested json settings file
    builder.AddJsonFile(name, optional, reloadOnChange);

    // Add all environment vars and build the ConfigurationRoot object. Then register it with the services container
    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    var config = builder.Build();

    // Register the resulting IConfigurationRoot to as a singleton
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

    return config;
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Configuration was lost because I created a new empty ConfigurationBuilder, added som json config and registered it. Adding the configuration already registered by the runtime did the trick! Thank you Nick!

Comment: This helped my issue. Thanks Nick. 
I think, this should be handled by default.

Comment: This has worked for me too. Not sure why this is not marked as the answer.

Comment: I would request OP if he/she can mark this as answer as it will help lot of people(seeing the popularity of the question) who are using custom startup, to resolve the issue quickly. I think removing the custom startup is not an option(or answer). Its like removing the code because its not working...!

Answer (score 3):

*I [responded](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/894#issuecomment-537692870) to the same (or similar) issue reported in github. To help others landing here, I am re-posting here.*

---

Adding a little more info for others that land here. Also, since I haven't seen anyone else mention this I may be interpreting/doing this wrong. If so, please speak up.

**Scenario**

- Functions v2 app, SDK 1.0.29
- C#
- using `[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]`
- Using `new ConfigurationBuilder()`, adding my config stuff
- Registering built `IConfigurationRoot` as singleton `IConfiguration`

**What I Observed**

Setting a breakpoint prior to adding my `IConfigurationRoot` and looking at the `IServiceCollection` I could see there was already a singleton `IConfiguration` registered. Furthermore, this instance had the provider for host.json in it, but it wasn't getting loaded when running in Azure.

**My Theory**

It appears that when two singletons of the same service are registered the DI framework will just grab the last added one.

**My Solution**

I extracted the existing `IConfiguration` provider from the `IServiceCollection` and added it to the `ConfigurationBuilder` so that its values are included in the `ConfigurationRoot` that I register and  therefore gets grabbed by the DI framework.

**Code**

```cs
public IConfigurationRoot AddSettings(IServiceCollection services, string basePath, string name, bool optional, bool reloadOnChange)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(basePath);

    var existingConfigs = services.Where(svc => svc.ServiceType.Name == "IConfiguration").ToList();
    foreach (var cfg in existingConfigs)
        builder.AddConfiguration((IConfigurationRoot) cfg.ImplementationInstance);

    // Register/load the requested json settings file
    builder.AddJsonFile(name, optional, reloadOnChange);

    // Add all environment vars and build the ConfigurationRoot object. Then register it with the services container
    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    var config = builder.Build();

    // Register the resulting IConfigurationRoot to as a singleton
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

    return config;
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone

Comment: The idea is there I think but this is not working for me. Maybe I am not calling this method properly? I am passing the `builder.Services` as the first argument. This builder is a `IFunctionsHostBuilder`. But then, then `cfg.ImplementationInstance` is null. Any other tricks?

Comment: I tired `service.Replace` in v3 but it does not work although `HostJsonProvider` is present in the configuration sources

Comment: Can someone show how to actually use this code please?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this! I used a small variation as I am utilizing the deferred invocation of the factory pattern to reference the config during startup:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddConfigurationFactory(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configurationEnvironment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConfigEnv");
    var jsonConfigFilename = $"appsettings.{configurationEnvironment}.json";

#if DEBUG
    var basePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
#else
    var basePath = @"/home/site/wwwroot";  
#endif
    var existingConfig = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType.Name == 
        nameof(IConfiguration));
    IConfiguration existingInstance = null;
    if (existingConfig != null)
    {
        var spOuter = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        existingInstance = spOuter.GetService<IConfiguration>(); 
    }
    Func<IServiceProvider, IConfiguration> factory = (sp) =>
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile(jsonConfigFilename, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                
        if (existingInstance != null)
            configBuilder.AddConfiguration(existingInstance);

        return configBuilder.Build();
    };
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(factory);
    return services;
}
```